# How to prove $\int_0^1\frac{x^3\arctan x}{(3-x^2)^2}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{192}\left(18-\pi-6\sqrt{3}\,\right)$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How to prove the following result?

> $$\int_0^1\frac{x^3\arctan x}{(3-x^2)^2}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{192}\left(18-\pi-6\sqrt{3}\,\right)$$

For my part no idea?

Comment: My long shot is to use $\arctan x=\Im\log(1+ix)$ then use differentiation under the integral sign. But it might lead to nowhere.

Comment: I'm leaving a comment here so I keep receiving notifications on this one. I am very curious what the solution pans out to

Comment: An interesting fact (despite the fact that I cheated by using WA) is that $$\int\frac{x^3}{(3-x^2)^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{2}}-\frac{3}{4}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{3-x^2},$$ so integration by parts followed by the residue theorem may be the way to go.

Comment: I will post my answer as soon as possible. The idea is to introduce two parameters.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas it has been solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bf{Modified:}$

Based on an idea from the solution of  @user111187:

Consider a general integral of the form

$$I_b =\int_0^1 \frac{R(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \arctan(b x)dx$$

with derivative 
$$J_b \colon =\frac{dI_b}{db} = \int_0^1 \frac{x\, R(x)}{(1+b^2 x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$$
and $I_0=0$.

The integral $J_b$ is doable if $R$ is a rational function. We get

$$I =I_1 = \int_{0}^1 J_b\, db$$

This last integral is doable in some cases.

In our case $R(x) = \frac{x^3}{(3-x^2)^2}$ so we get

$$J_b = \int_0^1 \frac{x^4}{(1+b^2 x^2)(3-x^2)^2  \sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$$

We find first the indefinite integral

$$\int \frac{x^4}{(1+b^2 x^2)(3-x^2)^2  \sqrt{1-x^2}} dx $$
One can check that it equals
$$
F_b(x):=\frac{3 x \sqrt{1-x^2}}{4 \left(1+3 b^2\right) \left(-3+x^2\right)}+\frac{3 \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \left(-1+b^2\right) \text{ArcTan}\left[\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}
x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right]}{4 \left(1+3 b^2\right)^2}+\frac{\text{ArcTan}\left[\frac{\sqrt{1+b^2} x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right]}{\sqrt{1+b^2} \left(1+3 b^2\right)^2}$$
Indeed, by direct calculations 
$$F_b'(x) = \frac{x^4}{(1+b^2 x^2)(3-x^2)^2  \sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

We get 
$$J_b = F_b(1_{-})- F_b(0) = \frac{\left(8-3 \sqrt{6}(1+b^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right) \pi }{16 \sqrt{1+b^2} \left(1+3 b^2\right)^2}$$

and therefore 
$$I = I_1 = \int_0^1 \frac{\left(8-3 \sqrt{6}(1+b^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right) \pi }{16 \sqrt{1+b^2} \left(1+3 b^2\right)^2} db = \frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{192}\cdot (\,18 - 6 \sqrt{3} - \pi) $$

This approach works for all integrals of form

$$\int_0^1 \frac{R(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \arctan(b x)dx=\int_0^1 \frac{x \, Q(x^2)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \arctan(x) dx$$

where $R(x) = xQ(x^2)$ is an odd rational function.

Comment: Tank for the answer

Answer (score 15):

Although integration by parts will work, a nice general way to attack the integral is by introducing

$$
J(a,b) := \int_0^1 \frac{x \arctan(ax)}{1-b^2 x^2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}},
$$
so $J(0,b) = 0$ and
$$
\begin{align}
\partial_a J &= \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{(1-b^2 x^2)(1+a^2x^2)} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{du\sec^2 u}{(\sec^2 u -b^2)(\sec^2 u +a^2)} 
\\&= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(t^2 + 1-b^2)(t^2 + 1+a^2)} = \frac{\pi/2}{\sqrt{1-b^2}\sqrt{1+a^2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-b^2}+\sqrt{1+a^2}},
\end{align}
$$
where $ x = \cos u, t = \tan u$, and the last equality follows easily using partial fractions.

Hence
$$
\begin{align}
J(1,b) &= \frac{\pi/2}{\sqrt{1-b^2}} \int_0^1 \frac{da}{\sqrt{1+a^2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-b^2}+\sqrt{1+a^2}}
\\&= \left.\frac{\pi/2}{\sqrt{1-b^2}} \frac{1}{b} \left[\arctan\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}\frac{\sqrt{1+a^2}}{a} \right)- \arctan \frac b a\right] \right\lvert_{a=0}^{a=1}
\\&= \frac{\pi/2}{\sqrt{1-b^2}} \frac{1}{b} \left[\arctan\sqrt\frac{2b^2}{1-b^2}- \arctan b\right].
\end{align}
$$

This implies that
$$
\begin{align}
&2b^{-3} \int_0^1 \frac{x^3 \arctan(x)}{(b^{-2} - x^2)^2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \partial_b J(1,b)
\\&= \frac{\pi}{2b^2(1-b^2)^{3/2}} \left\{b\frac{ \sqrt 2\sqrt{1- b^2}+2}{1+b^2}+\left(1-2b^2\right) \left[\arctan b-\arctan \sqrt{\frac{2b^2}{1-b^2}}\right]-b\right\}.
\end{align}
$$

Plugging in $b = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}$ simplifies this a lot, giving
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{x^3 \arctan(x)}{(3 - x^2)^2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} =\frac{\pi \sqrt 2}{192}\left[18-\pi - 6\sqrt 3 \right],
$$
as desired.

Comment: This is a good answer & I upvote it but it would be nice if you mention what kind of substitutions did you use to evaluate the integral. $$x\stackrel{?}\to u\stackrel{?}\to t$$

Comment: Magnificient proof, tank you infinitely(+1)

Comment: @user178256 Please consider accepting the answer if it is to your satisfaction.

Comment: very nice solution,very satisfied with your answer

Answer (score 5):

$$\newcommand{\b}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\d}{{\rm d}}
\newcommand{\f}{\frac}
\newcommand{\s}{\sqrt}
\newcommand{\t}{\text}
\newcommand{\u}{\underbrace}
\bf Answer$$

This belongs to a large category of functions that are easily solvable with integration by parts like:

> $$\int\frac{x\arctan(x)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\d x=\sqrt{1+x^2}\arctan(x)-\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2+1}|+c$$

---

So let our functions be:
$$f(x)=\f{x^3}{(3-x^2)^2\s{1-x^2}};g(x)=\arctan(x)\\\int f(x)g(x)\d x=g(x)\int f(x)\d x-\int g'(x)\u{\int f(x)\d x}_{h(x)}\d x$$
And(Beware I used Reduction Formula for evaluating last integral!):
$$\int f(x)\d x=\f12\int\f{t\d t}{(3-t)^2\s{1-t}}\quad(t=x^2)\\
=\int\f{u^2-1}{(u^2+2)^2}\d u=\int\f1{(u^2+2)}\d u-3\int\f{1}{(u^2+2)^2}\d u\quad(u^2=1-t)\\
=\frac1{\sqrt2}\arctan\frac u{\sqrt2}-3\b{\frac u{4(u^2+2)}+\f1{4\s2}\arctan\f u{\s2}}+{\cal C}\\
=\f1{4\s2}\arctan\s{\f{1-x^2}2}-\f34\f{\s{1-x^2}}{3-x^2}+{\cal C}=\t{(let) }h(x)$$
And thus:
$$\int g'(x)h(x)\d x=\f1{4\s2}\int \f1{1+x^2}\arctan\s{\f{1-x^2}2}\d x-\f34\int \f{\s{1-x^2}}{(3-x^2)(1+x^2)}\d x$$
So:

$$I=\int_0^1f(x)g(x)\d x=\b{\arctan (x)\b{\f1{4\s2}\arctan\s{\f{1-x^2}2}-\f34\f{\s{1-x^2}}{3-x^2}}}_0^1\\-\f1{4\s2}\int_0^1 \f1{1+x^2}\arctan\s{\f{1-x^2}2}\d x+\f34\int_0^1 \f{\s{1-x^2}}{(3-x^2)(1+x^2)}\d x\\
I=\f34\u{\int_0^1 \f{\s{1-x^2}}{(3-x^2)(1+x^2)}\d x}_{I_1}-\f1{4\s2}\int_0^1 \f1{1+x^2}\arctan\s{\f{1-x^2}2}\d x$$

Now:
$$I_1=\int_0^\infty\f{\d y}{4y^4+8y^2+3}\quad\b{x=\f{y^2}{y^2+1}\t{ or }y=\f{x}{\s{1-x^2}}=\tan\arcsin x \\\t{ which can also be obtained after two sunstitutions viz., }x=\sin z\t{, then }y=\tan z}\\
\f12\b{\f1{2y^2+1}-\f1{2y^2+3}}_0^{\infty}\\
=\f{3-\s3}{24}\pi\s2=\f{3-\s3}{24}\pi\s2$$

Still working on the last integral!!
BTW the final form is:
$$I=\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{192}(18-6\sqrt{3})-\f1{4\s2}\int_0^1 \f1{1+x^2}\arctan\s{\f{1-x^2}2}\d x$$
So it remains to prove:
$$\int_0^1 \f1{1+x^2}\arctan\s{\f{1-x^2}2}\d x=\pi^2/24$$

Comment: This is actually the approach I took at first. To evaluate the last integral, I integrated by parts and got something like $\int dx \frac{x \arctan x}{(3-x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. It is not really easier than calculating the general case $J(a,b)$.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{3}\arctan\pars{x}}{\pars{3 - x^{2}}^{2}}
     \frac{\dd x}{\root{1 - x^{2}}}=\frac{\pi\root{2}}{192}\,
     \pars{18 - \pi - 6\root{3}} \approx {\tt 0.1033}:\ {\large ?}}$

---

\begin{align}&\overbrace{\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{3}\arctan\pars{x}}{\pars{3 - x^{2}}^2}
\frac{\dd x}{\root{1 - x^{2}}}}}^{\ds{\dsc{x}\ \mapsto\ \dsc{\frac{1}{x}}}}\ =\
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan\pars{1/x}}{\pars{3x^{2} - 1}^{2}}
\frac{\dd x}{\root{x^{2} - 1}}
\\[5mm]&=\int_{1}^{\infty}\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\,\dd t}{t^{2} + x^{2}}}
^{\dsc{\arctan\pars{1/x}}}\
\frac{\dd x}{\pars{3x^{2} - 1}^{2}\root{x^{2} - 1}}
=\int_{0}^{1}\ \overbrace{\int_{1}^{\infty}
\frac{x\,\dd x}{\pars{x^{2} + t^{2}}\pars{3x^{2} - 1}^{2}\root{x^{2} - 1}}}
^{\ds{\dsc{x}\ \mapsto\ \dsc{\root{x}}}}\ \,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=\half\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{\infty}
\frac{\dd x}{\pars{x + t^{2}}\pars{3x - 1}^{2}\root{x - 1}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=\left.\frac{1}{18}\,\totald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{\infty}
\frac{\dd x}{\pars{x + t^{2}}\pars{x - \mu}\root{x - 1}}\,\dd t
\right\vert_{\mu\ =\ 1/3}
\\[5mm]&=\left.\frac{1}{18}\,\totald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}
\frac{1}{t^{2} + \mu}\braces{%
\underbrace{\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\dd x}{\pars{x - \mu}\root{x - 1}}}
_{\dsc{\frac{\pi}{\root{1 - \mu}}}}\ -\
\underbrace{\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\dd x}{\pars{x + t^{2}}\root{x - 1}}}
_{\dsc{\frac{\pi}{\root{t^{2} + 1}}}}}\,\dd t
\right\vert_{\mu\ =\ 1/3}
\end{align}
The '$\ds{x}$-integrations' were easily evaluated with the change
$\ds{\dsc{\root{x - 1}}\ \mapsto\ \dsc{x}}$. Note that
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\dd t}{t^{2} + \mu}
     =\frac{\arctan\pars{\mu^{-1/2}}}{\root{\mu}}}$. Namely,
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{3}\arctan\pars{x}}{\pars{3 - x^{2}}^2}
\frac{\dd x}{\root{1 - x^{2}}}}
\\[5mm]&=\overbrace{\frac{\pi}{18}\,\totald{}{\mu}\bracks{%
\frac{\arctan\pars{\mu^{-1/2}}}{\root{\mu\pars{1 - \mu}}}}_{\mu\ =\ 1/3}}
^{\dsc{-\,\frac{\pi\root{2}}{192}\,\pars{4\pi + 6\root{3}}}}\ -\,\,\,
\overbrace{\left.\frac{\pi}{18}\,\totald{}{\mu}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\dd t}{\pars{t^{2} + \mu}\root{t^{2} + 1}}
\right\vert_{\mu\ =\ 1/3}}
^{\dsc{-\,\frac{\pi\root{2}}{192}\,\pars{3\pi + 18}}}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\frac{\pi\root{2}}{192}\,
\pars{18 - \pi - 6\root{3}}} \approx {\tt 0.1033}
\end{align}
The last integral is evaluated as follows:
\begin{align}&\overbrace{%
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\dd t}{\pars{t^{2} + \mu}\root{t^{2} + 1}}}
^{\ds{\dsc{t}\ \mapsto\ \dsc{\frac{1}{t}}}}
=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{t\,\dd t}{\pars{1 + \mu t^{2}}\root{t^{2} + 1}}
=\half\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\dd t}{\pars{1 + \mu t}\root{t + 1}}
\\[5mm]&=\frac{1}{2\mu}
\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{\dd t}{\pars{t - 1 + 1/\mu}\root{t}}
=\frac{1}{\mu}
\int_{\root{2}}^{\infty}\frac{\dd t}{t^{2} + 1/\mu - 1}
=\frac{\arctan\pars{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\mu}-\half}}}
{\sqrt{\mu\pars{1 - \mu}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Tank for the answer.

Comment: @user178256 I'm glad it was useful for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial solution via contour integration. Start by rewriting the integral as

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^1 \frac{x^3 \arctan x}{\sqrt{1-x^2} \left(x^2-3\right)^2} \, dx \\
&= \frac12 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^3 \arctan x}{\sqrt{1-x^2} \left(x^2-3\right)^2} \, dx \\
&= \frac18 \int_0^\infty \frac{(1-y)^3 \arctan \frac{1-y}{1+y}}{\sqrt y \left(y^2+4y+1\right)^2} \, dy & \left[y=\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right] \\
&= \frac18 \int_0^\infty \frac{(y-1)^3 \arctan y}{\sqrt y \left(y^2+4y+1\right)^2} \, dy \\
&= \frac18 \left[J\left(\frac52\right) - 3 J\left(\frac32\right) + 3 J\left(\frac12\right) - J\left(-\frac12\right)\right]
\end{align*}$$

where we recall $\arctan\dfrac{1-y}{1+y}=\dfrac\pi4-\arctan y$ and notice that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{(1-y)^3}{\left(y^2+4y+1\right)^2} \,  \frac{dy}{\sqrt y} \stackrel{y\to\frac1y}= \int_0^\infty \frac{\left(y-1\right)^3}{\left(1+4y+y^2\right)^2} \, \frac{dy}{\sqrt y} = 0.$$

In the last step, we denote for a non-integer parameter $a<3$,

$$J(a) = \int_0^\infty \frac{y^a \arctan y}{\left(y^2+4y+1\right)^2} \, dy$$

and we may attack it by reproducing the method shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4835938/170231).

Comment: @170231 Exellent(+1)