# How to prove $\int_0^1 \frac1{1+x^2}\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}2}d x=\pi^2/24$?

Tags: contour-integration

Since I'm stuck at this final step of the solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1102616/67609). I wished to try contour integral, taking the contour a quadrant with centre ($0$) and two finite end points of arc at $(1),(i)$:
Then:
$$\operatorname{Res}\limits_{x=i}\frac1{1+x^2}\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}2}=-i\pi/8$$
But then:
$$2\pi i(-i\pi/8)=\pi^2/4??$$

Comment: You have to be careful when dealing with branch points.

Comment: You forgot to evaluate the integrals along $e^{i[0,\pi/2]}$ and $[i,0]$ as well.

Comment: Alternately, you might try differentiation under the integral sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over 1 + x^{2}}\,
     \arctan\pars{\root{1 - x^{2} \over 2}}\,\dd x={\pi^{2}  \over 24}:\
     {\large ?}}$.

---

In order to to 'remove' the ${\tt sqrt}$'s from the ${\tt arctan}$ function argument it's convenient to integrate by parts:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\arctan\pars{\root{1 - x^{2} \over 2}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm]&=\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ 1}
\arctan\pars{\root{1 - x^{2} \over 2}}\,\dd\arctan\pars{x}
=-\root{2}\int_{0}^{1}
{x\arctan\pars{x} \over \root{1 - x^{2}}\pars{x^{2} - 3}}\,\dd x
\end{align}

---

We 'avoid' the $\ds{\arctan\pars{z}}$ branch cuts by using an integral representation of it:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\arctan\pars{\root{1 - x^{2} \over 2}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm]&=-\root{2}\int_{0}^{1}
{x \over \root{1 - x^{2}}\pars{x^{2} - 3}}\int_{0}^{1}{x \over x^{2}t^{2} + 1}
\,\dd t\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=-\root{2}\int_{0}^{1}\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}
{x^{2} \over \root{1 - x^{2}}\pars{x^{2} - 3}\pars{x^{2} + t^{-2}}}
\,\dd x}^{\ds{\dsc{x}=\dsc{\cos\pars{\theta}}\ \imp\ \dsc{\theta}=\dsc{\arccos\pars{x}}}}\ \,{\dd t \over t^{2}}
\\[5mm]&=\root{2}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}\over
\pars{3 - \cos^{2}\pars{\theta}}\pars{t^{-2} + \cos^{2}\pars{\theta}}}
\,\dd\theta \,{\dd t \over t^{2}}
\\[5mm]&={\root{2} \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sec^{2}\pars{\theta}\over
\pars{\sec^{2}\pars{\theta} - 1/3}\bracks{\sec^{2}\pars{\theta} + t^{2}}}
\,\dd\theta\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&={\root{2} \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sec^{2}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta \over
\pars{\tan^{2}\pars{\theta} + 2/3}\bracks{\tan^{2}\pars{\theta} + 1 + t^{2}}}
\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&={\root{2} \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{%
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\sec^{2}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta \over \tan^{2}\pars{\theta} + 2/3}}
_{\dsc{{\root{6} \over 4}\,\pi}}\ -\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\sec^{2}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta \over \tan^{2}\pars{\theta} + 1 + t^{2}}}
_{\dsc{\pi \over 2\root{1 + t^{2}}}}}
\,{\dd t \over t^{2} + 1/3}
\\[5mm]&={\root{3} \over 6}\,\pi\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 1/3}}^{\dsc{\pi \over \root{3}}}\ -\
{\root{2} \over 6}\,\pi\ \overbrace{%
\dsc{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over \root{t^{2} + 1}\pars{t^{2} + 1/3}}}}
^{\dsc{3\pi \over 4\root{2}}}\ =\ {\pi^{2} \over 6} - {\pi^{2} \over 8}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{\pi^{2} \over 24}}
\approx {\tt 0.4112}
\end{align}

> The last integral can be evaluated as follows:

\begin{align}&\overbrace{%
\dsc{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over \root{t^{2} + 1}\pars{t^{2} + 1/3}}}}
^{\ds{t\ \mapsto\ {1 \over t}}}\ =\
3\int_{\infty}^{1}{-\dd t/t^{2} \over \root{1/t^{2} + 1}\pars{3/t^{2} + 1}}
=3\int_{1}^{\infty}{t\,\dd t \over \root{t^{2} + 1}\pars{t^{2} + 3}}
\\[5mm]&={3 \over 2}\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dd t \over \root{t + 1}\pars{t + 3}}\ =\
{3 \over 2}\ \overbrace{\int_{2}^{\infty}{\dd t \over \root{t}\pars{t + 2}}}
^{\ds{\dsc{t}\ \mapsto\ \dsc{t^{2}}}}
=3\ \overbrace{\int_{\root{2}}^{\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 2}}
^{\dsc{\pi \over 4\root{2}}}\ = \ \dsc{3\pi \over 4\root{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks. I was trying to integrate in the complex plane at my first attempt around a branch-cut in $\left(\,-1,1\,\right)$. However, I was rather cumbersome and I left it.

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer:** now I have a working real-analytic technique, but it is quite a *tour-de-force*.

We have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I &=& \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{2}}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{x}}\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{2}}\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{1}{(2-2x)\sqrt{1-2x}}\arctan\sqrt{x}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1/\sqrt{2}}\frac{x\arctan x}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1-2x^2}}\,dx\end{eqnarray*}$$
and integrating by parts we get:
$$ I = \sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2+x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos\theta\arctan\cos\theta}{3-\cos^2\theta}d\theta.\tag{1}$$
so:
$$ I = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos\theta\arctan\cos\theta}{3-\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos^{2n+2}\theta}{3-\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta.\tag{2}$$
On the other hand,
$$ I_n=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos^{2n+2}\theta}{3-\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta=-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^{2n}\theta\,d\theta+3 I_{n-1}=-\frac{2\pi}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}+3I_{n-1}\tag{3}$$
and $I_0=\pi\sqrt{\frac23}$. Now the plan is to solve recursion $(3)$ and compute the integral via $(2)$. 
$$ I = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{2\pi}{4^{n+m} 3^m}\binom{2n+2m}{n+m}\tag{4}$$
leads to:
$$ I = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{3^m(2n+1)}\binom{-1/2}{n+m}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m}x^{2n}\,dx}{3^m}\binom{-1/2}{n+m}\tag{5}$$
but since:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{s-1}(-1/3)^{s-n}(x^2)^n= \frac{1}{1+3x^2}\left((-1/3)^s-x^{2s}\right)$$
we have:
$$ I = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+3x^2}\sum_{s=1}^{+\infty}\left((-1/3)^s-x^{2s}\right)\binom{-1/2}{s}\tag{6}$$
and finally:
$$ I = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\frac{dx}{1+3x^2}\tag{7}$$
is easy to handle and leads to $\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{24}}$ as wanted, since:
$$ \int\frac{dx}{(1+3x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arctan\frac{x\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}.$$

Comment: how is {eqnarray*} or {eqnarray} different, what do you use them both for?

Comment: @ADG eqnarray* doesn't number the equations.

Comment: @ADG: yes, it is just because I prefer to number them with *\tag*.

Answer (score 3):

use the relation solved in this site
$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{\cos 2x }{2 \cos^2 x}}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{24}$$
Put $$\tan{x}=u, dx=\frac{du}{1+u^2}$$
 $$\sqrt{\frac{\cos 2x }{2 \cos^2 x}}=\sqrt\frac{1-u^2}{2}$$

Comment: (-1) A link-only answer, perhaps without a link. What kind of "answer" is that?

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio sorry, I do not know how a link.See also the review: The American Mathematical Monthly Problem E 2803[1979,149]Answers [1981,149]